# Edit in Word using Wopi and Office Online Server

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, outlook-web-app, ms-wopi

I am working on a project where we have implemented content management with word. 
We have some word files, that are being processed using OpenXML.
Users can open those files in two ways - download a copy or edit online. Online editing is implemented using Office Online Server and custom Wopi server, built based on [this example](https://github.com/marx-yu/WopiHost).

Editing online works fine, but Word Online has limited features compared to desktop Word.

I am trying to build a functionality similar to Sharepoint, where user has 2 options - Edit in Word, Edit in Browser:
[image: Sharepoint Word edit options]

In Office Online Server I don't have such options, I can only edit in browser:
[image: OOS Word edit options]

Even in edit mode Sharepoint provides a link for Edit in Word:
[image: Sharepoint in edit mode]

whereas Office Online Server does not have it:
[image: OOS in edit mode]

My question is how it is implemented in Sharepoint?
In other words, am I missing something in Wopi server to enable it or Microsoft has built this functionality into Sharepoint, without the need of Wopi and/or OWA?

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

To enable "Edit in Word" in Office Online Server when using a WOPI handler, you need to set the [ClientUrl](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#term-clienturl) property in CheckFileInfo (and CheckFolderInfo if you implement that). ClientUrl should be set to a direct editable link for the document file, either WebDAV or FSHTTP, but you could even use a file:// link for testing.

When you set the ClientUrl property, Office Online behavior becomes very similar to OneDrive/SharePoint Online. The current WOPI documentation is a bit outdated, it lists this property under **Unused and future properties**, but there is nothing secret about it. I asked dochelp@microsoft.com, that is Microsoft's "Open Specifications Support" mailbox, mentioned in many of their presentations and publications about WOPI and Office Online.

Word Online Reading View:

[image: Edit Document menu in Reading View]

Word Online Editing View after clicking OPEN IN WORD:
[image: 'Open in Word' menu behavior]

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that the functionality (Edit in Word) is not part of the Office Online Server and that it doesn't utilize the WOPI protocol. In the previous versions of SharePoint, it was implemented using WebDAV and I guess this hasn't changed. If you want to support opening/editing/saving you should implement your own WebDAV server. You can save a lot of time if you use a pre-built server like one from [ITHit](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/). They also have a JS framework to support [opening files from browser](http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/opening_ms_office_docs/).

If you want a cheap, cross-browser alternative that will just invoke the editing apps I suggest you have a look at [Office URIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx).

Comment: Sharepoint is using OOS and Wopi, according to this link: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_resource_kit/2012/09/11/introducing-office-web-apps-server/
Plus when you click on a document in Sharepoint it is open in WopiFrame.aspx, in which Word Editor from Office Online Server is loaded

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will investigate WebDav, it's seems like a viable option.