# How to set ClientUrl in ChekInfoFile in MS WOPI Office Online using WebDav

Tags: webdav, ms-wopi, office-online-server

I have developed MS WOPI that works on the browser, that is, we can view and edit documents stored in the database, in the browser. But I am unable to open the documents in MS Word desktop application.
I found in some answers here that we need to set the ClientUrl field of CheckFileInfo endpoint using WebDav.

I have no knowledge of WebDav, I tried to find more about it on the net but not able to fully understand it.

Just want to know what is the general format of the WebDav link for a specific file that we need to set in ClientUrl after we have set up a WebDav?

Is it something like this  https://serverAddressLockToken/FileName.ext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the WebDAV URL is not really important. A specific format of a URL won't make WebDAV work by itself. You need to implement a WebDAV server that will serve your files to client apps and will also define the format of accepted URLs.

WebDAV, similarly to WOPI, is quite a complex protocol and if you don't want to implement it from zero, I recommend using one of the available solutions, e.g. [ITHit's WebDAV Server](https://www.webdavsystem.com/).

There are also Office URIs that might pose an acceptable alternative for you. Check out my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37301342/1332034).